# Swipe event is triggered twice in jQuery Cordova Android

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, swipe, swiper.js

I have multiple page data in slide array, single swipe is registered as two swipes on 6.0(Marshmallow) version and later versions. I have tried these jquery methods but still triggers twice.

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
```

Code to handle swipe functionality,

```
                var wrap = jQuery('.slides_wrap'),
                slides = wrap.find('.img_slide'),
                active = slides.filter('.active'),
                i = slides.index(active),
                width = wrap.width();
```

Listen for swipe events on slides, and use a custom 'activate' event to add and remove the class 'active' to the previous or next slide, and to keep the index up-to-date. The class 'active' uses CSS transitions to make the slide move.

```
            slides

            .on('swipeleft', function(e) {
                if (i === slides.length - 1) { return; }
                //alert("swipeleft");
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                slides.eq(i + 1).trigger('activate');
            })

            .on('swiperight', function(e) {
                if (i === 0) { return; }
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                slides.eq(i - 1).trigger('activate');
            })

            .on('activate', function(e) {
                slides.eq(i).removeClass('active');

                jQuery(e.target).addClass('active');

                // Update the active slide index
                i = slides.index(e.target);
                activeSlide = i;
            })
```

The code below handles what happens before any swipe event is triggered. It makes the slides demo on this page work nicely, but really doesn't have much to do with demonstrating the swipe events themselves. For more on move events see: http://stephband.info/jquery.event.move

```
            .on('movestart', function(e) {
            //alert("movestart");

                // If the movestart heads off in a upwards or downwards
                // direction, prevent it so that the browser scrolls normally.
                if ((e.distX > e.distY && e.distX < -e.distY) ||
                    (e.distX < e.distY && e.distX > -e.distY)) {
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();

                    return;
                }

                // To allow the slide to keep step with the finger,
                // temporarily disable transitions.
                wrap.addClass('notransition');
            })


            .on('move', function(e) {
                var left = 100 * e.distX / width;
                //alert("move");
                // Move slides with the finger
                if (e.distX < 0) {
                    if (slides[i]) {
                        slides[i].style.left = left + '%';
                        slides[i+1].style.left = (left+100)+'%';
                    }
                    else {
                        slides[i].style.left = left/4 + '%';
                    }
                }
                if (e.distX > 0) {
                    if (slides[i]) {
                        slides[i].style.left = left + '%';
                        slides[i-1].style.left = (left-100)+'%';
                    }
                    else {
                        slides[i].style.left = left/5 + '%';
                    }
                }
            })

            .on('moveend', function(e) {
                wrap.removeClass('notransition');

                slides[i].style.left = '';

                if (slides[i+1]) {
                    slides[i+1].style.left = '';
                }
                if (slides[i-1]) {
                    slides[i-1].style.left = '';
                }
            });
```

HTML Code

```
 <div class="site_wrap wrap">
        <div class="img_slides_wrap slides_wrap wrap" id="contentDiv">
            <div class="pagination cent col-xs-12"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually swipeleft and swiperight were calling twice,thrice(in latest jquery lib), **.hasClass()** prevents the calling same function more than once.

```
.on('swipeleft', function(e) {
                    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                        if (i === slides.length - 1) { return; }
                        slides.eq(i + 1).trigger('activate');
                        swipeFlag = false;
                    }
                })

                .on('swiperight', function(e) {
                    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                        if (i === 0) { return; }
                        slides.eq(i - 1).trigger('activate');
                        swipeFlag = false;
                    }
                })
```